# NetworkOnMainThreadException in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

I am getting the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` while executing the two network requests in `AsyncTask`. In first request I get the `Response XML` and in second request, I download the `Image InputStream` to be used in `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`. Please find below the exception:

### NetworkOnMainThreadException

```
07-10 08:20:49.961: W/System.err(8570): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-10 08:20:49.961: W/System.err(8570):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
07-10 08:20:49.961: W/System.err(8570):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
07-10 08:20:49.971: W/System.err(8570):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
07-10 08:20:49.971: W/System.err(8570):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
07-10 08:20:49.971: W/System.err(8570):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
07-10 08:20:49.971: W/System.err(8570):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
07-10 08:20:49.981: W/System.err(8570):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:304)
```

### AyncTask

```
public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... object) {
        String url = (String)object[0];
        TASK_TYPE type = (TASK_TYPE)object[1];
        Object[] objects = new Object[4];
        switch(type)
        {
        case FETCH_NOTICES:
            publishProgress("Fetching notices ...");

             // Request # 1 to get the JSON XML

            String data = apiRequestGET(url);
            ArrayList<Notices> notices = extractUserFriendsDataFromXML(data);
            Notices notice = notices.get(0);

            publishProgress("Fetching done.");
            objects[0] = type;
            objects[1] = new ArrayList<Notices>(notices.subList(1, notices.size()));
            objects[2] = notice.getUniversityTitle();
            try {

             // Request # 2 to get the InputStream

                objects[3] = (InputStream) new URL(notice.getUniversityLogo()).getContent();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return objects; 
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String apiRequestGET(String requestString)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(requestString);

        String responseText = null;
        try 
        {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
            System.out.println("Some Response" +response);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
        catch (Exception e1) 
        {
            return e1.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        return responseText;
    }

}
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Two network requests in `doInBackground` can not be done?

Thanks in advance!

## Edit Full Stack Trace

```
07-10 08:52:18.672: W/System.err(9213): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-10 08:52:18.682: W/System.err(9213):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
07-10 08:52:18.682: W/System.err(9213):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
07-10 08:52:18.682: W/System.err(9213):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
07-10 08:52:18.692: W/System.err(9213):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
07-10 08:52:18.692: W/System.err(9213):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
07-10 08:52:18.692: W/System.err(9213):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
07-10 08:52:18.702: W/System.err(9213):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:304)
07-10 08:52:18.702: W/System.err(9213):     at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream.read(FixedLengthInputStream.java:45)
07-10 08:52:18.702: W/System.err(9213):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:168)
07-10 08:52:18.702: W/System.err(9213):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:309)
07-10 08:52:18.712: W/System.err(9213):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
07-10 08:52:18.712: W/System.err(9213):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:529)
07-10 08:52:18.712: W/System.err(9213):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:601)
07-10 08:52:18.722: W/System.err(9213):     at com.alpha.noticeslist.NoticeListActivity.dataFetched(NoticeListActivity.java:145)
07-10 08:52:18.722: W/System.err(9213):     at com.alpha.web.FetchDataTask.onPostExecute(FetchDataTask.java:124)
07-10 08:52:18.732: W/System.err(9213):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
07-10 08:52:18.732: W/System.err(9213):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-10 08:52:18.732: W/System.err(9213):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
07-10 08:52:18.732: W/System.err(9213):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-10 08:52:18.742: W/System.err(9213):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 08:52:18.742: W/System.err(9213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-10 08:52:18.752: W/System.err(9213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 08:52:18.752: W/System.err(9213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 08:52:18.752: W/System.err(9213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-10 08:52:18.752: W/System.err(9213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-10 08:52:18.762: W/System.err(9213):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I get the error while a function called from `onPostExecute` inwhich `InputStream` is being passed as:

```
public void dataFetched(InputStream inputstream)
    {       
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputstream);
            logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

### onPostExecute

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result){
        statusDialog.dismiss();
        Object[] objects = (Object[])result;
        TASK_TYPE type = (TASK_TYPE)objects[0];
        switch(type)
        {
        case FETCH_NOTICES:
        ((NoticeListActivity)callerActivity).dataFetched((InputStream)objects[3]);
        break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why I am getting down voted? I am performing two requests in `AsyncTask` and getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, Its problem that I am facing, Why down voted instead of answers?

Comment: What did you learn when you Googled for this exception or read some of the hundreds of questions on this site related to it?

Comment: how you are calling AsyncTask.. can we see the code

Comment: @Simon: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` occurs when you try to run network request on main thread, I am performing network requests in `AsyncTask`, still gets the exception. Its also mentioned in the Question header.

Comment: @DCoder: `FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
  task.execute(url, TASK_TYPE.FETCH_NOTICES);`

Comment: are you sure that the stacktrace points to this AsyncTask?

Comment: Post your full logcat trace and highlight the exact line in which you are getting the error

Comment: `decodeStream` reads from an InputStream. From where does this InputStream came? Is it the result of a Network operation?

Comment: Yes, it is coming from `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask`

Comment: post your `onPostExecute` method

Comment: ` @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Object result){
  statusDialog.dismiss();
  Object[] objects = (Object[])result;
  TASK_TYPE type = (TASK_TYPE)objects[0];
  switch(type)
  {
  case FETCH_NOTICES:
  ((NoticeListActivity)callerActivity).dataFetched((InputStream)objects[3]);
  break;
  }
 }

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting the error because although you get a reference to the `InputStream` in your background thread, you actually read from the stream when you call `decodeStream` in `onPostExecute`, which runs on the main thread

Move the call:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputstream);
```

into `doInBackground` and pass the `bitmap` back rather than the inputstream

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are calling to `myFetchDataTask.execute()`. Are you calling to `doInBackground()` directly, if that is the case it will not work, if not, please post how you execute your `AsyncTask`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: `FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
  task.execute(url, TASK_TYPE.FETCH_NOTICES);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for async task:

```
private class FetchDataTask  extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void>

{
Object[] objects = new Object[4];
protected void onPreExecute() {
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... paramsObj) {
    String url = (String)object[0];
    TASK_TYPE type = (TASK_TYPE)object[1];

    switch(type)
    {
    case FETCH_NOTICES:
        publishProgress("Fetching notices ...");

        // Request # 1 to get the JSON XML

        String data = apiRequestGET(url);
        ArrayList<Notices> notices = extractUserFriendsDataFromXML(data);
        Notices notice = notices.get(0);

        publishProgress("Fetching done.");
        objects[0] = type;
        objects[1] = new ArrayList<Notices>(notices.subList(1, notices.size()));
        objects[2] = notice.getUniversityTitle();
        try {

            // Request # 2 to get the InputStream

            objects[3] = (InputStream) new URL(notice.getUniversityLogo()).getContent();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) 
{
    // Do action with objects
}

}
```

From the calling method, use:

```
new FetchDataTask().execute();
```

Comment: in what should it be better?

Comment: @blackbelt: I am giving suggestion to use the objects in onPostExecute method. Also informing how to call the async task method. I dont think it deserves a down-vote!

Comment: even though, how it is related to his stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

your class sholud be:

```
class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Void> 
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
            //code here

            publishProgress("");

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
```

you can execute like `new FetchDataTask.execute([your parameter]);`